# UK Visa For Fiance

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, spouses

I'm on a tier 2 general visa in the UK and I would like to invite my fiance to visit me for 3 weeks. Is it advisable to invite her on a visitor visa instead of Tier 2 dependent visa ? 
The reason I want to bring her on visitor visa is she will be away from the UK for 6 months after this visit which might affect the ILR application later on. 
We have strong ties back in the country to show that she will go back after her visit. She will get a NOC letter from her university stating the same. 
If it's advisable to bring her on visitor visa, should I mention the reason for not applying for a Tier 2 Dependent visa on the covering letter or will it complicate things ?

Comment: How does your fiancée qualify as dependent?

Comment: She is not dependent on me right now but will be dependent after the wedding. I will provide marriage certificate to show that we are married and she will stay with me after wedding. As far as I understand, spouse of a Tier 2 General Visa holder is treated as a dependent. Hope my understanding is correct.

Comment: You said fiancée, not spouse :-)